# Free parking in downtown Mountain View?

Tags: automobiles, san-jose-california, silicon-valley

What's the situation with parking in Mountain View, CA, the US of A?

Is there free parking?  Meters?  Parking structures?

Comment: Meta discussion: [To park for free or not to park for free?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1345/to-park-for-free-or-not-to-park-for-free)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

City of Mountain View, CA, has no street meters that I know of, so, all parking is free, even covered parking!

When visiting the downtown at Castro St, there is some street parking right on Castro St, as well as several parking lots, and even two several-story parking structures (on the west side of Castro St), all free.

Generally, there is a limit on daytime parking, of 2 or 3 hours, but in the evenings, you can generally park for as long as you want.

Map here: http://www.mountainview.gov/images/2013ParkingMap_2.jpg

Comment: And if you don't mind a 10 minute walk, you can park all day in the mostly residential streets a bit further away